# Should I configure my New RAID5 Drives as MBR or GPT?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, mbr, gpt

I have a new RAID-5 Setup on a Server here at work. I have just created the RAID-5, and its size is a little over 2.7 TB.  Now, Iknow that MBR does not support anything over 2.2 TB, however, I have seen several posts online saying that certain operating systems, such as Windows XP 32-bit, cannot read GPT Disks.  Now, if I set this up as GPT and Partitioned it into several Drives for the server, would users on XP32 be able to see and use these drives on the network, or can they actually not see them at all?

Comment: What operating system does "Server" run, and what network sharing mechanism? (e.g. Linux/Samba).

Comment: The Host Server is running Windows Server 2012.  The VM Servers running off of it are Server 03/08 R2, depending on the server.

Comment: However, the server in question is a physical, off-site server running 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

1. The only thing that matters is the OS on your server.  Your client machines do not matter.  Systems access the volume via the network all via the server OS.  Client systems simply have no visibility into physical storage.
2. The MBR has a 2TB limit for the entire drive.  You cannot setup MBR on a 2.7TB volume and partition out smaller drives.  If you use MBR, the maximum storage you use on that volume is 2TB, everything else will be wasted.
3. As to if you can use GPT or not.  It completely depends on your server OS, and the system.  If those are the only drives in your system, you are running Windows and your computer doesn't support EFI, then you are kinda out of luck.

Comment: My Server OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.  So, basically, as long as the server can read the drives, I can share them and the Users on WinXP32 can use those for data?  This basically what I am asking.  I don't think the OS would be recommending GPT if it wasnt supported.

Comment: It isn't clear to me.  Is this RAID5 volume being used for the OS, or purely as a data volume.  If it is purely for data, and you have 2008, then no problem.  Go with GPT.  IF you plan on installing the OS on this drive, then that gets a bit trickier.   Go ahead and try it though.  It shouldn't hurt anything.  It will either work or not.

Comment: Ok, Yeah, it's just a Data Partition, no OS on it or anything